# Java network programming - only local sockets

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I need to code Java server and client using the local sockets. I know how to do this in C. I found many examples on internet with code examples how to write Network Java server and client but I can't find a good example only with local sockets. Is there any good example?

Best Wishes

Comment: any particular reason why you've tagged Java EE on this question?

Comment: You can't use local(unix) sockets in Java if that's what you mean - at least not without writing a JNI C library that you use from the Java code.

Comment: Is there any other way to bridge the two languages?

Comment: How does a "local socket" differ from a TCP connection over loopback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean Unix Domain sockets?

https://github.com/mcfunley/juds is one option.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html seems to be a good one.